# how to use nokogiri to dump the schema elements form a xml file?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

i have a xml file like this : https://gist.github.com/1966260。

I want to dump the schema elements(xs:element).

I try :

```
doc.xpath("//xs:element")
doc.xpath("//element")
doc.xpath("element")
```

dont work....

any advice ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('https://raw.github.com/gist/1966260/8769a795b2ba83ceea6aaa45365b01cf344087b0/gistfile1.xml'))
doc.xpath('//xs:schema', 'xs' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
```

I'm not sure yet if this is a bug with nokogiri or the intended behavior, but it'd be worth discussing on the mailing list or creating an issue for.

Answer (score 2):

@BenTaitelbaum That is the intended behavior. http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath.

Different documents can give different prefixes for the same namespaces. For example, this document uses "xs" as the namespace prefix for 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'. But some other document may use "xmls" instead. By providing the namespace mapping, the `xpath` method will always find the nodes that are in the 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' namespace, even if the prefix is different. They do this because URLs are universally unique, but the prefixes are not and could clash, and using the URL on every node would be tedious and waseteful, not that XML has ever had qualms with that (zing).

A good read: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/04/23/namespaces-in-xml/

Your way is right/good/healthy. But in the spirit of completeness, here are some other options that are shady and might hurt you:

If you want to query by the namespace prefix instead of by the URL (which is probably a bad idea), you can [collect all the namespaces](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-collect_namespaces) beforehand. (This only works if the urls in the document map 1-to-1 with prefixes. If they don't, this may fail)

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(the_url))
namespaces = doc.collect_namespaces
doc.xpath('//xs:schema', namespaces)
```

If you want to completely ignore namespaces (which is probably a bad idea), you can [remove them entirely](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces-21).

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(the_url))
doc.remove_namespaces!
doc.xpath('//schema')
```